# Binding predicates in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to reuse some expressions in a Prolog rule.

For example, consider the following fact:

```
predicate(
    complicatedPredicate(foo1, foo2, foo3),
    complicatedPredicate(foo1, foo2, foo3)
).
```

How could I bind the first complicatedPredicate so I don't have to type the whole thing again?

To be clear, I want something that acts like this:

```
predicate(Binding<-complicatedPredicate(foo1, foo2, foo3), Binding).
```

Comment: Write it as a rule: `predicate(X, X) :- X = complicatedPredicate(foo1, foo2, foo3).`?

Comment: You can do `Binding = complicatedPredicate(foo1, foo2, foo3), predicate(Binding,Binding)`

Comment: What you've created is a fact, not a rule. `predicate(A,A)` will do the same thing you want now, where it checks whether for `predicate(Arg1,Arg2).` are functionally identical, even though they can be different references. Of course this is the same as basic unification predicate `=(A,B)` and you could just write A = B somewhere in a rule and if their instantiated atoms can be made identical, the result will be yes.

Comment: @G_V this fact does not behave as predicate(A,A). For example, predicate(A,A) will unify with predicate(foo1,foo1), while my fact does not.

Comment: @Jsevillamol - Your question is about predicate usage, not how to check for `complicatedPredicate(foo1, foo2, foo3)` specifically. Obviously if you need something more specific, you just build something more specific. `predicate(A,A).` does EXACTLY what you asked for. It binds the more complex term `complicatedPredicate(foo1, foo2, foo3)` to A and then checks whether the second argument is identical to `complicatedPredicate(foo1, foo2, foo3).`.

Comment: I believe either what I commented or what @TomasBy commented behaves as you have asked, unless there's more to the problem that you haven't shared.

Comment: @lurker yes, that works for me!